# Neptune throwing "Host did not respond in a timely fashion" when trying to connect from private EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-neptune

I have created a neptune instance and per the [documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-console.html)...

I create the following yaml...

```
hosts: [xxx.xxx.us-east-2.neptune.amazonaws.com]
port: 8182
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
```

And when I try to connect everything seems to work I see...

> ==>All scripts will now be sent to Gremlin Server - [xx.xx.us-east-2.neptune.amazonaws.com/172.xx.x.xxx:8182] - type
>   ':remote console' to return to local mode

What am I missing why is the query failing?

Comment: Looks like it must be a security group `curl -G http://your-neptune-endpoint:8182/status` returns AccessDenied. I double checked and my Security Group has the following TCP rule...

`Custom TCP Rule
TCP
8182
0.0.0.0/0`

Comment: Is there anything else you'd like answered in this question?

Answer (score 2):

Have you enabled IAM authentication on your instance? 
If yes, you will have to perform some [additional steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/iam-auth-connecting-gremlin-console.html) to connect to the DB.

If no, double check the following:

1. EC2 instance is in the same VPC as the cluster.
2. Check the inbound settings for security group attached to the cluster and outbound setting for your EC2 instance.

If it still doesn't connect, I would suggest you to contact AWS Support.

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to connect from your pc or ec2 instance ?
I think that Neptune is not publicly accessibly 
create ec2 instance in the same VPC and try to connect from it

Comment: Yes I am sshed into the EC2 instance